# Most relevant categories in categorical variables for Random Forest models (or for general black box models)

Tags: random-forest, interpretation

Suppose I want to predict if a person is committing fraud and I only have his/her `age` and `city`, where `age` of course is a continuous variable and `city` a categorical one.

I'd like to have an idea of what ages or cities of residence are predictive of a high probability of fraud.

With `age` I could do a a partial plot  (see [partialPlot](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/randomForest/versions/4.6-12/topics/partialPlot) for an implementation) to see how the response variable or the probability of fraud changes with different age values.

However, with the variable `city`, I'm not sure what to do.
I'd like to have a list of, say, the 10 cities that cause a biggest change in probability of fraud. Bonus points if there's a library that addresses this.

Thanks for your time!

----- EDIT ------

I've read some of the literature on marginal effects for non-linear models (see [this summary](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/margins/vignettes/TechnicalDetails.pdf). They distinguish between:

- Marginal effects at representative values (say, at the median of the other variables)
- Average Marginal effects (discretize the support, calculate the effect of a city and then average those effects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to run predictions for all cities and collect those with the highest predicted probability for fraud.

However, random forests are strong at fitting nonlinearities and interactions, so if you use an RF, I assume you expect some such effect. Thus, the impact of `city` may depend on the value of `age`. At lower ages, different cities may be hotbeds of fraud than at higher ages. So I'd recommend that you also vary the setting for `age` in your predictions. In such situations, I like to use the three quartiles of `age` observed in the training data.

I am not aware of any libraries doing this, but the scripting should be straightforward. You may want to look at [variable-importance](/questions/tagged/variable-importance) in the context of random forests, which is a related but different concept.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, that sounds like a good start. I've edited my question to include info on Mg Effects at Representative values (which sounds like what you're suggesting) vs average marginal effects. I probably implement it the one you suggest without too much hassle.